# How to control localization settings in the iNotes calendar control?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

The "extLib" iNotes calendar control appears to have a "life of its own" when it comes to localization settings:
in the week views e.g. weekday and month names are following the localization settings of the client (if I set the browser's language to en-US it says "Monday" ... "Sunday"), but the week always starts at Monday. Another example are the time slots where they are displayed: times are always displayed as "09:00" .. "12:00" and then onwards as "13:00" .. "18:00" etc. But there are also "AM" and "PM" markers where applicable, no matter what locale the client is set to (see screenshot #1 below for a de-DE locale).

[image: ExtLib iNotes calendar control]

This behavious is *not true* for the "real" iNotes calendar: this one follows the client's locale as can be seen in the 2nd (locale = de-DE) and 3rd (locale = en-US) screenshot below (ok, for en-US week still starts at Monday, but this can be set through the iNotes preferences).

[image: iNotes calendar using de-DE locale]

[image: iNotes calendar using en-US locale]

So I wonder if, no I really **hope that** there's some way to control localization parameters. But how?

Comment: I would say because no one seams to have the answer, download extension library and read the sourcecode for clues how to do it.

Comment: Added an answer for similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18419096/2065611