# XPages iNotes Calendar

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

How do you control the display of the time and dates on the iNotes Calendar control in an XPage?  I would like to have the times shown using the 12 hour format hh:mm AM and the date to use MMM dd, yyyy.

Thank you.

Comment: Here is the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902334/how-to-control-localization-settings-in-the-inotes-calendar-control but unfortunately without an answer.

Comment: I would say because no one seams to have the answer, download extension library and read the sourcecode for clues how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The date and time format for iNotes Calendar is defined in language files for the most common languages. These language files are **specific** for iNotes Calendar.

They are stored in `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_x.x.x.xxxxxxxx-xxxx.jar` file in folder `DominoServerPath\data\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins`.

If you unpack the jar file (it's just a zip file) you'll find a folder `resources\web\dwa\date\nls` and there the language specific subfolders like `de`, `en`, `en-gb`, `en-ie` and `en-us`. The date and time format is definied in that subfolders in file `calendar.js`.

This file starts e.g. for `en-us` with the lines:

[image]

Surprisingly, the date and time format is not right for the US `en-us`. Same for `en`, `en-gb` and `en-ie`. I'd call it a bug or at least a wrong packaging.

If you change the time format line to `D_DTFMT_TIME0: "hh:mmt"` then you get your 12 hour time format with am/pm.

Close to setting `D_DTFMT_TIME0` are all the other settings for date and time formatting.

So, change all `en` languages files with the appropriate values, save them back to the jar file and restart the Domino server.

Just for further research: the date and time values get formatted with the help of `...jar\resources\web\dwa\date\dateFormatter.js`.

Comment: Not very intuitive.  I will give it a try

Comment: I added some details to my answer - hope it's more intuitive now.

Comment: Sorry I meant that IBM did not make it very intuitive.

Comment: I see :) - this date/time formatting is rather an Extension Library bug and no one would have to know about language files if they would  just work like expected for certain languages. So, this answer is more about fixing the bug and yes, this is not very intuitive.

Comment: @awsllc: Could you get it to run?